# What could be causing my computer to boot in emergency mode?

Tags: linux, mount, startup

I haven't had any issues with booting up until I recently moved to a new house.  Upon setting it up again, I get the following when booting up:

> You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journaltcl -xb to
> view system logs, "systemctrl reboot" to reboot "systemctl default" or
> "exit" to boot into default mode.
>
> Press Enter for maintenance (or press ctrl-d to continue):

Upon hitting ctrl-d, I can see that the drive /dev/sdb1 is not mounted.  That drive is normally mounted as /home.  If I manually mount it there and continue booting up, everything runs fine.  If I then reboot the computer though, I get the same issue.

When I run "journalctl -xb", here are the lines relevant to sdb (each ellipsis representing skipped text):

```
...
Dec 27 12:40:00 wonder kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
Dec 27 12:40:00 wonder kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
Dec 27 12:40:00 wonder kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Dec 27 12:40:00 wonder kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Dec 27 12:40:00 wonder kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
Dec 27 12:40:00 wonder kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Dec 27 12:40:00 wonder kernel:  sdb: sdb1
Dec 27 12:40:00 wonder kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
...
Dec 27 12:40:02 wonder systemd-fsck[1030]: /dev/sdb1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
...Dec 27 12:40:03 wonder systemd-fsck[1030]: /dev/sdb1: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.
Dec 27 12:40:03 wonder systemd-fsck[1030]: /dev/sdb1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
Dec 27 12:40:03 wonder systemd-fsck[1030]:         (i.e., without -a or -p options)
Dec 27 12:40:04 wonder systemd-fsck[1026]: fsck failed with exit status 4.
Dec 27 12:40:04 wonder systemd-fsck[1026]: Running request emergency.target/start/replace
...
Dec 27 12:52:51 wonder kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb1): error count since last fsck: 1
Dec 27 12:52:51 wonder kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb1): initial error at time 1701887868: ext4_orphan_get:1254
Dec 27 12:52:51 wonder kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb1): last error at time 1701887868: ext4_orphan_get:1254
...
```

Can anyone suggest/explain what the cause of this is?  It apparently occurred when moving it to a new town. I didn't check much physically, just that the drives are secured properly and still properly connected.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now feel silly having asked the question, as it is now solved by running fsck on /dev/sdb1 as suggested in the logs.  The system now boots properly.